# First word of a comma separated sentence php

Tags: php

My string is : Hi my, name is abc

I would like to output "Hi Name".

[Basically first word of comma separated sentences].

However sometimes my sentence can also be Hi my, "name is, abc"

[If the sentence itself has a comma then the sentence is enclosed with ""].

My output in this case should also be "Hi Name".

So Far I've done this

```
$str = "hi my,name is abc";
$result = explode(',',$str); //parsing with , as delimiter 
foreach ($result as $results) {
    $x = explode(' ',$results); // parsing with " " as delimiter 
        forach($x as $y){}
    }
```

Comment: "name is" will be there in all the inputs ?? is it like "name is xxxx" ?

Comment: @BSB No.. This string is just an example

Comment: @Ank Try this one https://eval.in/865129 I am assuming you have one `,` in the statement

Comment: Why do I have downvotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `explode` to achieve YOUR RESULT and for IGINORE `'` OR `"` use trim

```
$str = 'hi my,"name is abc"';
$result = explode(',',$str); //parsing with , as delimiter 
$first = explode(' ',$result[0]);
$first = $first[0];

$second = explode(' ',$result[1]);
$second = trim($second[0],"'\"");
$op = $first." ".$second;
echo ucwords($op);
```

**EDIT** or if you want it for all , separated values use foreach

```
$str = 'hi my,"name is abc"';
$result = explode(',',$str); //parsing with , as delimiter 
$op = "";
foreach($result as $value)
{
    $tmp = explode(' ',$value);
    $op .= trim($tmp[0],"'\"")." ";
}
$op = rtrim($op);
echo ucwords($op);
```

Comment: works.. but I get trailing spaces at the end. For second solution

Comment: try edited answer. added `rtime` to remove space from rightside

Answer (score 0):

Basically it's hard to resolve this issue using explode, str_pos, etc. In this case you should use state machine approach.

```
<?php
function getFirstWords($str)
{
    $state = '';
    $parts = [];
    $buf = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($str); $i++) {
        $char = $str[$i];

        if ($char == '"') {
            $state = $state == '' ? '"' : '';
             continue;
         }

         if ($state == '' && $char == ',') {
             $_ = explode(' ', trim($buf));
             $parts[] = ucfirst(reset($_));
             $buf = '';
             continue;
         }
         $buf .= $char;
    }
    if ($buf != '') {
        $_ = explode(' ', trim($buf));
        $parts[] = ucfirst(reset($_));
    }

    return implode(' ', $parts);
}


foreach (['Hi my, "name is, abc"', 'Hi my, name is abc'] as $str) {
     echo getFirstWords($str), PHP_EOL;
}
```

It will output `Hi Name` twice

[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/25dd907eb1bce7cdb80cba2ecaceb5d29058ccdc)